# Смена типа члена базового класса в производном?

Tags: c++

Есть ли возможность сделать, чтобы член базового класса, менял тип в производном, если в производном определен тип имеющий такое же название как и у его типа?

Чтобы было проще можно представить, что rb_tree::NODE имеет название rb_tree::rb_NODE.

```
struct search_tree
    {

    struct NODE
    {
    NODE * parent;
    NODE * left;
    NODE * right;
    };

    NODE * root;

    // функция поиск максимального ключа
    // использует член search_tree::root
    int max_()
    {
    root;
    return 1;
    }

    insert();
    find();
    delete();
    min();

    search_tree::search_tree(){root = new NODE;}

    };

    struct rb_tree : public search_tree
    {
    // можно также назвать rb_NODE
    struct NODE : public search_tree::NODE
    {
    char color;
    };

    //!! вот здесь главный смысл. 
    // попытка присвоить rb_tree::NODE  тип search_tree::NODE
    // меня интересует, чтобы при создании объекта root имел
    // тип rb_tree::NODE
    int insert()
    {
    NODE * node2;
    node2 = root;
    }

    delete();

    };
```

Общая суть такая:

```
1) класс search_tree реализован, там есть
insert
find
delete
max
min

2) класс rb_tree подобен search_tree
изменяется только 
insert
delete

 Но в rb_tree тип NODE должен иметь
 поле color. Соответственно методы
 rb_tree:: используют rb_tree::NODE, а
 методы search_tree:: search_tree::NODE
```

Конечно проще всего просто в классе search_tree добавить в тип NODE поле color а rb_tree::NODE удалить, сейчас так и сделано.

Но меня интересует именно возможность реализации как в вопросе.

Comment: Сделайте `search_tree` и `rb_tree` шаблонами от типа `TNode`.

Answer (score 1):

То, что описано в задаче, очень похоже на такую штуку, как **Двойная диспетчеризация**. Этот же принцип используется в паттерне посетитель (Visitor).

> Двойная диспетчеризация вызова - это возможность динамически определить исполняемый метод не только на основе типа объекта, над которым метод выполняется (поддерживается явным образом в C++, Java и любом другом объектно-ориентированном языке), но и на основе информации о типах аргумента, доступной на этапе выполнения и недоступной статически (на этапе компиляции). (взято [здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID9/7220.html) )

Почитайте ссылки ниже и я думаю, Вы найдете правильное решение задачи, возможно небольшой модификацией кода.

- [Шаг 14 - Двойная диспетчеризация. Продолжение](http://www.firststeps.ru/theory/c/r.php?14)
- [Двойная диспетчеризация – двойное удовольствие](https://web.archive.org/web/20150914145412/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ruericlippert/archive/2009/04/09/9692868.aspx)

Ну и гугл никто не отменял + книги Скота Маерса.

Comment: Вообще не очень понял на счёт этого. Информации очень мало.
Вроде бы похоже. 
Здесь имеется ввиду перегрузка функций для разных типов? 
То есть определение методов надо выносить из класса?
Как и другие советуют делать через шаблоны?

Answer (score 1):

Что делать - Котик уже объяснил:  шаблонизация функции - самое простое и надежное.

Почему так. Тип Node в классе search_tree и rb_tree - разные типы. Один называется search_tree::Node, другой - rb_tree::Node.